# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect- when uploading a file

Tags: java, spring, jquery, file-upload

I get the follwing exception when i try to upload a file in spring :

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

this is how i submit the value through ajax :

```
function uploadComment(viewName,answers){
    var file_data = $("#CIMtrek_daily_originator_comments").val();
    alert("file_data "+file_data);
    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_FileUpload",
            data: {
                uploadFile : file_data,
                id : '0'
            },
        success: function (msg) {
            global.getElementById("CIMtrek_uploadedFileName").innerHTML=msg;
             alert("File Uploaded");
        }
    });

}
```

and this is my controller method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_FileUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createComments(@RequestParam("uploadFile") MultipartFile  uploadItem ) {
        System.out.println(" CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_FileUpload : ");
        String uploadedFileName="";
        try {
            String fileName = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            if (uploadItem.getSize() > 0) {
                inputStream = uploadItem.getInputStream();

                System.out.println("size::" + uploadItem.getSize());
                fileName = "/WEB-INF/resources/Attachment/"+ uploadItem.getOriginalFilename();

                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                System.out.println("fileName:" + uploadItem.getOriginalFilename());

                int readBytes = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            }
            uploadedFileName =uploadItem.getOriginalFilename();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return uploadedFileName;
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use serialize() instead of val() as below

data: $("#your_form").serialize();

```
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
contentType:false,
url : "CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_FileUpload",
data: $("#your_form").serialize(),
    success: function (msg) {
        global.getElementById("CIMtrek_uploadedFileName").innerHTML=msg;
         alert("File Uploaded");
    }
});
```

Comment: I am sorry your answer did not help me, could you elobarate your answer as where to put this code  if you don't mind?

Comment: No, `CIMtrek_daily_originator_comments` Is the html input file name.

Comment: In controller you are looking for "uploadFile", you need to use the input file name here. If CIMtrek_daily_originator_comments is your input file use that in controller. Also have you added multipart resolver bean ?

Comment: I have added `multipart resolver bean` and changed the input `file`  name to `CIMtrek_daily_originator_comments` This is the exception i get now ,Error: ReferenceError: attr is not defined

Comment: This is my multipart resolver bean <beans:bean  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
      <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
      <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
  </beans:bean>

Comment: can you set contentType to false and try

Comment: This `,Error: ReferenceError: attr is not defined ` is gone but still file upload is not working